# Creating a Per-User dynamic connection string for ASP.NET website connecting to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamic, connection-string

Per-user (dynamic) connection strings for Asp.Net website. I have seen some posts on dynamic connections for Linq, but we use straight ADO connections.

ASP.NET website: hosted in IIS, the connection string is straight-forward - no linq or entity or other layers

Dmmmied-up example connection string in `web.config` is

```
<connectionStrings>      
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=yada.yada;Persist Security Info=True; Password=yadaPassword;User ID=yadaUser;Initial Catalog=YadaDatabase" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Single Web Portal for MULTIPLE CUSTOMER users; the goal: connect to a DIFFERENT database and/or database server for each unique user - 1 login per user  - 1 unique connection string per user  because there will be 1 unique database for each user

Process Support : when a new user subscribes, our support folks can create / add other connection strings to the `web.config` if needed  Our folks manually create a UNIQUE database for each new user/customer - which is what we want to connect to.

The SITE is a master/content page model so we will implement the configuration-on-the-fly in the MASTER page - we are doing that now with some session IDs for different users in the same database but for scalability we MUST deploy a separate database for each user/customer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please spend some time and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) to get accustomed to site, specifically [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you give each user a access token after login (Oauth2 bearer token or similar)? Having the username as a claim in an access token makes it easy to generate connection strings in code per call. Adding new connection strings to web.config will force the web application to restart every time a new customer is added. Having potentially thousands of connection strings in web.config is probably not a good idea either.